# Convergence of a sequence for the three-point set

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, convergence-divergence

In Munkres Topology section 17 in the subsection on Hausdorff Spaces there is a motivating example involving the three-point set  $\{a, b, c\}$  which states that the sequence defined by setting

$x_n = b$

converges to $a$, $b$ and $c$.

I have read the explanation for this but am still finding it difficult to see why this is true, could someone give some further detail on why this happens please?

Thank you.

Comment: It's page 98 and 17.3 in the latest (2nd) edition.

Comment: It's on page 96 in my copy, which is also the second edition.

Comment: I think this may be due to there being different international editions available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In asking a related question (which can be found here 
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2959100/226937 ) I also found the answer to this question.

For $X=\{a,b,c\}$ with the trivial topology of $\ \mathcal{T}=\{∅,X\}\ $ the limit of a sequence will be all elements in the set $X$ since the smallest open set in the topology (i.e. the set $X$) which contains the limit point also contains all other points in $X$. This would also be the same for any set of a finite number of elements equipped with the trivial topology.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be any set. Consider the topology $\mathcal{T} = \left\{ \emptyset , X \right \}$. Let $p \in X$ be a point and let $x_n = p$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Now suppose that $q \in X$. We will prove that $x_n$ converges to $q$. To see this, let $U$ be an open set containing $q$. Since $U \neq \emptyset$, $U = X$. Let $N=1$. Then for all $n>N$, we have $a_n =p \in X =U$. Since $U$ were arbitrary, we have proved that $a_n$ converges to $q$.

Comment: Thank you for your response, just a query, is the $a_n$ the same as $x_n$ here? Also is the 'idea' of this proof that since both p and q both fall within the open set U and you have shown that U is all of X this means that $x_n$ converges to both points? And so would it always be that case that the sequence could converge to any point in this space? Would this for example still be true if there were an infinite number of points in X? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Oh. The topologies are not coincides. Actually, I don't have that book. So I guessed the topology in question. But the nature is same. They are too coarse.

Answer (score 1):

The topology there in the book is in fact $\{a,b\}, \{b\}, \{b,c\}\}$. So every open set in the topology contains $b$, so the sequence $b,b,b,\ldots$ converges to all $3$ points by the definition given in the text: take $N=1$ always.

Comment: Thank you for this, I hadn't noticed the topology indicated by the diagram was indeed the one that you have suggested here. Does this alter the result? Should I edit my answer to change the topology? Also as a question on convention the diagram has a circle around all three elements, so does this indicate that {a, b, c} is also in the topology?

Comment: If the smallest open subset of the topology you have suggested is just b is there a reason this sequence converges to all three elements? Is that because you have taken N=1? If it were possible to take N=0 for example would it just converge to b?