# Convergence of a constant sequence in a set of finite elements

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, convergence-divergence

In Munkres Topology section 16 in the subsection on Hausdorff Spaces there is a motivating example involving the three-point set $\{a,b,c\}$ which states that the sequence defined by setting

$x_n=b$

converges to $a$, $b$ and $c$.

In any finite set of elements would a constant sequence always converge to all elements in the set?

If you could also provide any examples or counter examples that would be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Convergence depends on the topology - what topology are you giving your set? If it's the discrete topology (I.e all subsets are open) then your convergence claim is false. If you are equipping your set with the trivial topology (i.e only the whole set and the empty set are open) then your claim is true.

Comment: It is with the trivial topology I believe, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A constant sequence $(a_n)$ always converges to the constant value $a=a_n$. That doesn't depend on the underlying topology.

Any other limit depends on topology. In particular if $U$ is the smallest open subset containing $a$ then every element of $U$ is a limit point of $(a_n)$. Such $U$ doesn't have to exist of course, but in finite spaces it always does (or in other words: finite spaces are [Alexandrov spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_topology)). Of course there might be more limit points then $U$.

For example, let $X=\{1,2,3\}$. We will consider different topologies on $X$:

1. $\mathcal{T}=\{\emptyset, X\}$, i.e. the anti-discrete topology. Then any point is a limit of any constant (or not) sequence;
2. $\mathcal{T}=\mathcal{P}(X)$, i.e. the discrete topology. Then any constant sequence has exactly one limit - the constant value. In fact for finite spaces this is equivalent: every convergent sequence has exactly one limit if and only if $X$ is discrete;
3. $\mathcal{T}=\{\emptyset, X, \{1,2\}\}$. Then each sequence $a_n=1$ and $a_n=2$ has three limit points: $1,2,3$, while the sequence $a_n=3$ has only one limit point, namely $3$.
4. $\mathcal{T}=\{\emptyset, X, \{1,2\}, \{3\}\}$. Then the sequence $a_n=3$ again has exactly one limit point: $3$. But now sequences $a_n=1$ and $a_n=2$ have two limit points each, namely $1,2$.

Each example can be directly calculated from the definition of a limit point and I encourage you to do that.

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful, especially your 3rd point, which I think has clarified this for me. I think what Munkres is saying is that with the trivial topology the smallest set in the topology already contains all 3 elements so the convergence is to all 3 since all of the elements are arbitrarily close, is this along the right lines?

Comment: @robotsheepboy Actually the original claim in my 3rd point was wrong. I had to rebuild the example a bit. Anyway yes, the trivial topology almost always means the anti-discrete topology. So having only one nonempty open subset means that everything is a limit for everything.

Comment: Great, that is really helpful, thank you.

Comment: I am coming back to this after some time, but am now finding myself slightly confused. In example 3 the smallest open subset containing the point 1 is {1,2} so why is it that all of 1, 2 and 3 are limit points instead of just 1 and 2? Likewise for the point 2 in the same example.

Comment: @robotsheepboy That's because you should look at neighbourhoods of those limit points. Not smallest open subsets. In example (3) take $x=3$ as a limit point. According to the defintion $x$ is a limit point if *every* neighbourhood of $x$ contains almost all elements of the sequence. So what are neighbourhoods of $3$? It is whole $X$ only. Thus its a limit point of every possible sequence, in particular a constant one.

Comment: great, that has cleared it up, thanks for getting back to me so quickly and for providing such illustrative examples, it has really helped me to understand

Answer (score 0):

If the topology is Hausdorff, a convergent sequence converges to a unique limit. If for $x_n\rightarrow x$ you have an open neighbourhood $U$ such that $x\in U$ and $y\notin U$, then $x_n$ does not converge to $U$.

Furthermore a topology is Hausdorff if and only if limits of nets (generalization of sequences) are unique.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, so in this case with the three element set the trivial topology would not be Hausdorff, but is there a particular reason _why_ would it converge to all three elements?

Answer (score 0):

A simple observation:
If $X$ is a finite space, TFAE:

1. $X$ is discrete.
2. $X$ is Hausdorff.
3. Every constant sequence has a unique limit.
4. $X$ is $T_1$.

**Proof**

$1 \to 2$: Is clear as all discrete spaces are trivially Hausdorff.

$2 \to 3$: Is a standard result for all sequences (not just the constant ones)

$3 \to 4$: If there'd be an $x \in X$ such that $\{x\}$ is not closed, then there'd be some $y \in X, y \neq x$ with $y \in \overline{\{x\}}$, which means that every neighbourhood of $y$ contains $x$ as well. This implies that the constant sequence with value $x$ converges to both $x$ and $y$, contradicting $3$. So all singletons are closed and $X$ is $T_1$.

$4 \to 1$: As $X$ is finite (here we use it), all subsets are closed (and thus also open) when all singletons are.

In short, any non-discrete finite space will have a constant sequence converging to another point besides its own constant.